# Ruby on rails, Change column value on update of other column value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have two columns related to each other in a Rails model:

```
Article.body
Article.body_updated_on
```

I want to change the `Article.body_updated_on` to `Time.now`, every time `Article.body` is updated. If any other fields updated nothing needs to be happen.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just add before save callback to your Article model

```
class Article < ActiveRecord:Base

  before_save :update_body_modified

private       # <--- at bottom of model

  def update_body_modified
    self.body_updated_on = Time.now if body_changed?
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either override the default setter for body, or better yet, use a [callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#callbacks-overview) to set it just before update.   You could choose from several options: before_save, before_update ... depending on exactly when you want it.

```
 before_save do |article|
   article.body_updated_on = Time.now if article.body_changed?
 end
```