# Rails 5 - update Model A's datetime based on model B's new datetime

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Project` and a `Task` model.

Project has `start_date` and `end_date`
Task has `task_start_date` and `task_end_date`.

How can I make it do Project's `start_date' is the earliest`task_start_date`and the same for`end_date`?

Task is a child of Project (if it matters).

I have done some [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397776/ruby-on-rails-change-column-value-on-update-of-other-column-value) and I believe a 'Before Save' is what I want, but I'm unsure how to implement this similarly.

I've tried

```
dev update_project_record
        self.project.start_date = self.task_start_date if self.task_start_date < self.project.start_date 
    end
```

and it seems to be working if I am to make the change within Rails Console, but if I use the app itself, it doesn't actually make the change to the `Project`. How should I modify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) I was able to figure out the issue of association.

```
[12, 21] in /home/ubuntu/workspace/sow_trip/app/models/task.rb
   13:     
   14:     private
   15:     
   16:     def update_project_record
   17:         byebug
   18:         #self.project.start_date = self.task_start_date if self.task_start_date < thisProject.project.start_date 
   19:         #self.project.end_date = self.task_end_date if self.task_end_date > self.project.end_date 
=> 20:     end
   21: end
(byebug) self
#<Task id: 31, task_name: "Fail Me Boo", comment: nil, task_start_date: "2016-05-05 00:00:00", task_end_date: "2020-02-20 00:00:00", project_id: 1, created_at: "2017-08-23 06:10:31", updated_at: "2017-08-23 06:10:31", product: "D", document_id: 1>
(byebug) project
#<Project id: 1, name: "Demo Test", project_type: "Misc", cost: "7500", start_date: "2017-05-01 00:00:00", end_date: "2017-07-28 00:00:00", created_at: "2017-08-23 02:39:44", updated_at: "2017-08-23 06:10:10", client_id: 1>
(byebug) task
```

Using some light console play led me to realize `project` is already defined within this call, so I don't need to search the instance of `self`.

```
def update_project_record
    project.start_date = self.task_start_date if self.task_start_date < project.start_date 
    project.end_date = self.task_end_date if self.task_end_date > project.end_date 
end
```

Is my final code for anyone looking - as I could not find a similar situation.

I used `belongs_to :project, touch: true` to automatically update the `updated_at` fields, but I have a custom datetime that a 'Project' should have the earliest-possible-`state_date` and the latest-possible-`end-date`